# How to make a for loop stop after 20 repetitions in C

Tags: c

I need help making my for statement stop when it reaches 20 lines of repetition at most. In other words the length doesn't have to reach the value 20, but the table has to stop after 20 lines of the table have been completed. At the moment I have everything right it's just that it will continue to go past 20 lines of the table and it will eventually stop when it reaches the numerical value of 20. I know that it is because my conditional statement has the length <= to 20 but I don't know how to write it differently to only get 20 repetions instead. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.141592

double pendulum_Period(double length);
int main()
{
double length;
double updateLength;



printf("\nThis program displays a table of Pendulum lengths and their respective period.\n"
       "\nPlease enter the length of the pendulum(ft):  ");
scanf("%lf", &length);

if( length <= 0 )
{
    printf("\n\nError: Length must be > 0\n"
           "Please enter the length of the pendulum(ft):   ");
    scanf("%lf", &length);
}


printf("\n\nPlease enter the updated value for the length(ft):  ");
scanf("%lf", &updateLength);



 printf("\nLength(ft)\t\t\tPeriod(s)\n"
        "------------------------------------------\n");


for( length = length; length <= 20 && length > 0; length+= updateLength)
{
    double period = pendulum_Period(length);
    printf("%.6f\t\t\t%.6f\n", length, period);
    printf("------------------------------------------\n");
}


return 0;
```

}

```
double pendulum_Period(double length)
{

    double T;
    double period;
    double gravity;
    gravity = 32.2;
    T = (2 * PI)*(sqrt(length/gravity));
    period = T;

    return period;
}
```

Comment: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Answer (score 0):

Need to use i since that is what is set to length.

```
for( i = length; i <= 20; i+= updateLength)
{
    double period = pendulum_Period(i);
    printf("%.6f\t\t\t%.6f\n", i, period);
    printf("------------------------------------------\n");
}
```